# Windows cmd python subprocess.call

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have a command which I can run manually from the windows command prompt, and it works as expected:

```
> gridcoinresearchd sendmany "Default" {"""x9Bqs6dTm17tsiEyZ9m4j5Yd8N2dpqw""":1.00000000} 2 "Hello World"
```

So I build my subprocess.call() as follows from a set of variables, some of which are derived from other variables, where;

```
call_insert = [val for pair in zip(quotes, quotes, quotes, address, quotes, quotes, quotes, colon, call_amount, comma) for val in pair]
call_insert = str("{"+(''.join(call_insert))+"}")
account_label = str('"'+(raw_input("Choose Account Label: "))+'"')
message = str('"'+(raw_input("Enter if you wish to send a message: "))+'"')
```

then:

```
subprocess.call(['gridcoinresearchd', 'sendmany', account_label, call_insert, "2", message], shell=True)
```

when using the subprocess.call I get an error from the target program:

```
error: Error parsing JSON:{x9Bqs6dTm17tsiEyZ9m4j5Yd8N2dpqw:1.00000000}
```

if I manually make the variable:

```
call_insert = str("""{"x9Bqs6dTm17tsiEyZ9m4j5Yd8N2dpqw":1.00000000}""")
```

then my subprocess.call() works.

So this I think is my confusion with how the windows command prompt is interpreting the quotes I need in my subprocess.call() strings.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK by trial and error I found that the string must be in this form:

```
{"x9Bqs6dTm17tsiEyZ9m4j5Yd8N2dpqw":1.00000000}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we inspect the given error message

```
{x9Bqs6dTm17tsiEyZ9m4j5Yd8N2dpqw:1.00000000}
```

and compare it to your desired JSON input

```
{"""x9Bqs6dTm17tsiEyZ9m4j5Yd8N2dpqw""":1.00000000}
```

we can see that double quotes are missing in the first statement, and it is probably the main reason why JSON is not parsed.

So basically I may suspect that `call_insert` variable is not formed as you expected, i.e. does not contain double quotes, and is equal to:

```
str({x9Bqs6dTm17tsiEyZ9m4j5Yd8N2dpqw:1.00000000})
```

I suggest you to look closer into the first 2 lines of your example and into the code above it to check its output.